# Python subprocess and raw_input

Tags: python, subprocess, raw-input

Ok thanks everyone for help. I've second problem. I want chat when I watch stream and it's possible with irc. Server is `irc.twitch.tv` and channel is same as livestreamer name. When I tried this code, it gives me error.

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-  
import subprocess  
print(35*"+")  
name = raw_input("Livestreamer name\n")  

hostVideo = subprocess.Popen(['livestreamer', 'twitch.tv/'+name, 'best'], stdout  =        subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]  
hostIrssi = subprocess.Popen(['irssi --connect=irc.twitch.tv --password=oauth:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --nick=nickname'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]  

print hostVideo
print hostIrssi
```

This is error what I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Livestreamer.py", line 7, in <module>
hostIrssi = subprocess.Popen(['irssi --connect=irc.twitch.tv --password=oauth:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --nick=nickname'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Also if possible, tell me how to make it join automatically right channel.

**MY older post**

I love watching twitch livestreams and I wanted to do script which asks livestreamer name and then send commands to terminal.
Livestreamer command is like

```
livestreamer twitch.tv/user best
```

So script must add "twitch.tv/" after livestreamer command and "best" after user.
My code looks like:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import subprocess
user = raw_input("Livestreamers name:\n")
livestreamer = "livestreamer twitch.tv/"
host = subprocess.Popen(['livestreamer', 'twitch.tv/', user, 'best'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

print host
```

Output is

```
livestreamer: error: unrecognized arguments:  best
```

If someone know whats wrong, Im so glad that. Also sorry my bad english. :)

Comment: unrelated: you could replace `output = subprocess.Popen(..).communicate(..)[0]` with `output = subprocess.check_output(['livestreamer', 'twitch.tv/' + sanitize(user), 'best'])` or if you don't need the output: `subprocess.check_call([..], stdout=DEVNULL)`. Though It seems `livestreamer` doesn't generate much output and therefore there is no issue with accumulating the whole subprocess' output in memory as `.communicate()`/`check_output()` functions do.

Comment: you should put *"OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"* problem into a separate question. Though the answer is the same as for *"livestreamer: error: unrecognized arguments:  best"* error, namely: one command-line argument -> one list item.

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate `"twitch.tv/"` with the username, so your final line should be

```
host = subprocess.Popen(['livestreamer', 'twitch.tv/'+user, 'best'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Also note that keyword (`name=value`) arguments shouldn't really have spaces around the equals sign for best conformance to the Python style guide in [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: `twitch.tv/<user>` is an url. Don't use `os.path.join('twitch.tv', user)` to create an url. You could use `'twitch.tv/' + urllib.quote(user, safe='')` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed that from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your subprocess line is sending this command:

```
livestreamer twitch.tv/ user best
```

This would start a process in the form of your example:

```
subprocess.Popen(['livestreamer', 'twitch.tv/%s' % user, 'best'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```